# Ensuring all subscriptions are done before calling connect on a ConnectableObservable

Tags: rx-java

I have a [`ConnectableObservable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/ConnectableObservable.html) and multiple subscribers. And subscriptions are happen in different threads by using [`subscribeOn`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html) operator.

Problem is that I want to call [`connect`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/connect.html) operator when all subscriptions are done because I don't want any subscribers miss any packets.

But I cannot make sure if all subscribers have subscribed the observable because it happens on different threads.

Also I don't want to use [`replay`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html) operator. There is no reason to cache all packets just because of async subscriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the exact number of `Subscriber`s and the only action you want is to connect when all of them are ready then use `autoConnect(int)`.